# Android studio instrumented apk error while running application

Tags: android, android-studio, monkeytalk

I have created one hello world demo and try to create an instumented apk using monkey talk with below link
http://www.jiahaoliuliu.com/2015/02/monkey-talk-integration-with-android.html

I don't found any error in build.gradle file in app module
Below is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-aspectj'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "packagename"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21


    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }

        monkeytalk.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        monkeytalk {
            applicationIdSuffix ".monkey"
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.1'
    //    GCM gradles
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    //    Map & location
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    //facebook
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.9.0'
    compile project(':calenderLib')
    // Dependency for Google + Sign-In
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
    // Dependency for Google Sign-In
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    compile files('monkey-libs/monkeytalk-agent-2.0.10.jar')
    monkeytalkCompile fileTree(dir: 'monkey-libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

While running application i found below error,

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > No such property: bootClasspath for class: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin

I am using android studio version `1.5.1` and monkey talk `monkeytalk-2.0.10-win64`

Error screen shot

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

see this document [link](https://prativas.wordpress.com/2014/08/15/using-monkeytalk-in-androidstudio/)

no need of using

> > monkeytalkCompile fileTree(dir: 'monkey-libs', include: ['*.jar'])

this give me error when i am running the project

no need of writing

> > monkeytalk.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
> >             monkeytalk {
> >                 applicationIdSuffix ".monkey"
> >     }

just use this :

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

i think this will help, if anyone is facing problem please let me know. My build is successfully running on monkeytalk IDE

Comment: I have followed same steps as suggested and removed that code but still getting same error.

Comment: have you checked bellow link ??